# Changing the color of deleted lines in a diff

Tags: git, powershell, git-diff

When I run the Git diff command from within a Powershell terminal window, the deleted lines are shown in a dark red color on a dark blue background. It is extremely difficult for me to see the actual code.

Is there a Git setting or Powershell setting that will allow me to change this color? Most of the answers I found only deal with the status of the change (modified, staged, etc.) I need to change the color of the deleted line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a collection of git configuration values that control the color output from various commands.  In this case you want something like

```
git config --global color.diff.old <new-color>
```

There are a couple ways to specify the color, and this may depend on terminal support.  I've had good luck with basic color names in most cases ('blue', 'bold yellow', ...)

See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config for additional settings that are available.

Another option is to suppress color altogether, as in

```
git diff --no-color
```

Comment: Works perfectly! The documentation also mentions attributes like bold and italic, but I couldn't get that part to work.

Comment: It should just be a matter of listing the words in the setting. However, `git config` takes its arguments as space-separated, so `git config color.diff.old bold yellow` means: *for `color.diff.old` entries that match `yellow`, replace them with `bold`.* To replace all old entries, you need: *for `color.diff.old` entries, replace them with `bold yellow`* which is written as `git config color.diff.old "bold yellow"` (single and/or double quotes depending on your shell).

Comment: You might find it easier to run `git config --global --edit`, which will bring up your global configuration file in your editor, where you can edit each line individually, and not have to deal with your shell.